# html & js - load resources from client local path instead of server path

Tags: javascript, html, path, localhost

this is the scenario of my question: I have a web page that shows some images throug jquery dom injection, like this:

```
<!-- this is inside an html page -->
<img id="img1" src="#" />
<img id="img2" src="#" />
<img id="img3" src="#" />
```

and this is an example of the script I use to load the images

```
$("#img1").attr("src", "/img/image1.jpg");
$("#img2").attr("src", "/img/image2.jpg");
$("#img3").attr("src", "/img/image3.jpg");
```

so the full path for the images is www.mywebsite.abc/img/someImage.jpg

what I need to do, is to find a way to switch the images source path, and force the page to load them from a local (client) path, for example c:\something\img.

the img folder structure will be the same both for the server and for the client, so basically what I think that the browser has just to "switch" from server to client, taking the images from the client's folder instead of server's folder as soon as he needs them.

do you think it's possible to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion/answer, if you need more clarification, just ask.

best regards, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no, you can't do that. The browser's security features won't let your page access files on the filesystem. However, if you're using this in some limited scope where you control the client machine, you may be able to use command line switches to disable that piece of security.

For example, you can launch Chrome with `--allow-file-access` and then do

```
$("#img3").attr("src", "file://c/something/img/image3.jpg");
```

I wouldn't recommend it, though, and obviously general users won't be launching Chrome that way.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need this in a normal web page/application. If what you want is to **spare network traffic**, then you can serve the files from the server with the proper caching headers.
Then, after the first request, the client's browser will retrieve the file from the cache (filesystem), not even bothering your web server.

For comprehensive tutorial on HTTP Caching see http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/.

Doing what you're suggesting is kind of obscure, and browsers most likely block that. Even if they didn't, you never know the filesystem that the client might have.
Always develop your web page/application in the most client agnostic way possible.

After this, if you still want to do that for some reason, then other answers here may point you to the "right" direction.

EDIT:

There is another possibility. HTML5 has the possibility of offline web applications. Basically you provide a list (a *manifest*) of the resources you want to be available offline. Any HTML5 Offline capable browser will parse this list and download and cache the files listed in there, even if the user didn't need that particular file yet (user doesn't need to visit every corner of the website). The browser automatically keeps copies of these files up to date when online.

I think this might be what you're looking for.

See http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html for more information and list of compatible browsers.

Comment: +1 for caching, since I'm *guessing* that network performance is the OP's motivation.

Comment: Actually, I need to let an user to fully visit a website offline, without having to visit every corner of the website to download every image and cache it. the steps are: user connects to www.something.com, downloads index (based on jquerymobile, so every page he needs is inside the index), disconnects from the internet, choose a local path where he can find every image he needs, browse offline. I know it sounds weird..

Comment: download as in `file -> save as` or download as in browse to that URL and its now showing in the browser? Because if the index also gets served off the file system, the browser will be willing to load images via file:// paths. Where you'll run into trouble is having the index's origin be something.com and all the assets on the local filesystem. That doesn't work.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please let me know if that was what you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think why you want to do this but try

```
$("#img1").attr("src", "file:///img/image1.jpg");
```

or

```
$("#img1").attr("src", "file://img/image1.jpg");
```

it may work